# can etherscan.io show local ganache transaction details?

Tags: tokens, metamask, dapps, openzeppelin-contracts

I am purchasing tokens on my sample Dapp with ganache-cli account using metamask.

Metamask shows the confirm message and deduct the ether from total balance but in token section it still not update and still zero in tokens.

Following is the screenshot

[image]

on etherscan.io no transaction
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4e1ea5da31ba7d5bca6c8b45a3d705df3151f067adfc07b7502e04bec6a84733

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Etherscan will only show the details of the publicly available data relating to the public main and test networks.

`ganache-cli` runs an in-memory test framework that mimics a real blockchain on your local machine. Etherscan has no knowledge of what happens on you local machine.

---

> on etherscan.io no transaction
>   https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4e1ea5da31ba7d5bca6c8b45a3d705df3151f067adfc07b7502e04bec6a84733

You are querying a transaction on the Ethereum main network that doesn't exist. This transaction only exists on your local machine.